# Specifying the shape of pulse in RoughFrequencyCal

Tags: qiskit, openpulse, ibm-q-experience

I've been following upon this document for device calibration.
https://qiskit.org/documentation/experiments/tutorials/calibrating_real_device.html

Is there any way to specify the pulse shape for the RoughFrequencyCal experiment? I think the default pulse shape being used is the Gaussian. I wanted to use a different pulse shape for the experiment. Any idea on how can I achieve this?